# Seeking help on explanation for a big combination algorithm

Tags: javascript, math, combinations

A recent [CodeSignal Challenge](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/a8GNsYr8FQxZmMhJj?solutionId=MZQa7pP2nzgzzoSev) was to calculate 1000C500 (mod 1e9+7) and I got defeated.

All my trials exceeded the time limit. Here is the [best JS solution by psr](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/a8GNsYr8FQxZmMhJj?solutionId=MZQa7pP2nzgzzoSev). Could anyone explain what happens in this line? I learnt ES6 but got no idea about its syntax `f[o = n + 1/k] = o in f` ...

```
f = nCk = (n, k) => f[o = n + 1/k] = o in f
    ? ...
    : ... 
        ? n && ...
        : ...
```

Some lines are masked to avoid violation of rule

Comment: That's short for `o = n + 1/k; f[o] = o in f;`.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow has few rules about posting code from wherever you want. The place you are copying code from may have rules against copying code from their site. By copying the code here, you are (re)licensing the code under the CC-by-SA 4.0 license. "psr" may or may not be happy with that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks but I am still confused about ```f[o] = o in f```
here ```o``` is a newly assigned decimal, and ```f[o]=o``` is to assign o into property o of f ? and check whether it is ```in f``` ??

@HereticMonkey Thanks for reminding, is it ok to mask out a few lines?

Comment: `o in f` is being used as the condition in the ternary expression. So it's assigning one value if `o` is already a key in the `f` object, and assigning a different value if this is a new key.

Comment: This is common when using an object property as a counter; you initialize the counter to `1` the first time, and subsequent times you increment it.

Comment: I don't see the code at the link you provided, I just see an empty function named `countWays()`. Is that because I don't have an account there?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I have posted my own understanding as an answer below. You have to register (free) if you wanna check the link above. Thank you again! Good luck hacking=)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barbar's explanation in question comment, I understand the algorithm now.

The algorithm can be rewritten as follows:

```js
f = nCk = (n, k) => {   //Declare both f and nCk as the same function
let o = n + 1/k         //o will be the key of function object f
f[o] = o in f           //Define f[o] based on a nested ternary expression
    ? f[o]              //Avoid recalculation if f has key o already 
    : k==0              //nC0 is always 1
        ? 1
        : n<k           //nCk is improper and assigned 0 if n<k
            ? 0
            : f(--n, k) //Do recursion nCk = (n-1)Ck + (n-1)C(k-1)
            + f(n, k - 1) 
return f[o]             //Done!
}
```

Here goes an example of 5C2

```
f(n,k)  n   k   o   f[o]
f(5,2)  5   2   5.5 f[5.5]=f(4,2)+f(4,1)=10
f(4,2)  4   2   4.5 f[4.5]=f(3,2)+f(3,1)=6
f(3,2)  3   2   3.5 f[3.5]=f(2,2)+f(2,1)=3
f(2,2)  2   2   2.5 f[2.5]=f(1,2)+f(1,1)=1
f(1,2)  1   2   1.5 f[1.5]=f(0,2)+f(0,1)=0
f(0,2)  0   2   0.5 f[0.5]=0
f(0,1)  0   1   1   f[1]=0
f(1,1)  1   1   2   f[2]=f(0,1)+f(0,0)=1
f(0,0)  0   0   Inf f[Inf]=1 //Inf aka Infinity
f(2,1)  2   1   3   f[3]=f(1,1)+f(1,0)=2
f(1,0)  1   0   Inf f[Inf]=1
f(3,1)  3   1   4   f[4]=f(2,1)+f(2,0)=3
f(n,0)  n   0   Inf f[Inf]=1
f(4,1)  4   1   5   f[5]=f(3,1)+f(3,0)=4
```

P.S. I got a few takeaways when investigating into this algorithm

1. Double declaration of function on the same line as a trick for recursion
2. Immediate use of a key with its value just assigned
3. Infinity can be used as a key of an object(!)
4. Syntax `o in f` checks if object f has the key o

Comment: What makes the original code is confusing is that it uses such compact format. If you split it into separate statements, add temporary variables, change the ternaries to if/else, it will become much clearer.

Comment: It also confusingly uses the function itself as the object to store the data. It was deliberately written to be confusing.

Comment: @Barmar The rule takes only competence and length of code into account, and I am quite shocked when bumped into this solution ^^"